# Visual Studio hangs when changes are made to source codes in Asp.Net App_Code folder

Tags: visual-studio, performance, app-code

My Visual Studio will hang everytime I make some small changes to the Codes in the App_Code folder.

I checked in the folder.. there are about 91 Files in 62 Folders.

Any suggestions on how I can improve its performance?

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar report on the connect.microsoft.com site. The microsoft solution pointed to a plugin Document!X, but that didn't seem to cover all reported cases. There are a couple of comments which states that the problem occurs without the plugin (like this post).

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/368690/visual-studio-2008-sp1-ide-temporarily-freezes-when-saving-code-files

Other people in my office have also confirmed that this problem is happening for them. Maybe it's a common plugin we all use. But, I'm hoping there is a setting we can change to prevent this.